# Moving from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, migration, mysql-8.0

I'm currently running MySQL 5.7 in one of the key servers. This version reaches end of life soon, so it's time to move to 8.0. Or give it a shot and jump on 8.1?

This one is also running on dated operating system, which also reaches EOL in mid next year.
I'd like to move it in one shot on fresh OS. It's production env, so downtime should be limited to minimum, but basically it is accepted for some time.

Requirements and notes:

1. Data integrity - it's key of course.
2. All user related settings, credentials etc. should be also moved.
3. Settings. On one hand I'd like to copy all of this to quickly kick of on 8.0, but on the other hand I think we have gained some extra settings over the years. Not sure if this is obsolete or not.
4. New machine (VM) will have more RAM, CPU and storage, so I don't have any hard capacity limits or frames to fit.
5. Old and new VM is(will be) Linux.

Now the question, what is the best way to move?

1. Lock tables, make a dump on 5.7 and re-create from dump on 8.0?
2. Make replication from 5.7 to 8.0, test and stop 5.7 after testing?

Comment: I've completed the migration. It was very helpful to work with the Update Checker mentioned in links above. There was quite a lot things to align, including charset, some broken things, some config details. Finally I did the upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0 with full dump and restored this on new host. It took me a while to complete all preparations. It was very helpful to work on VM copies before I hit the prod one. Before the process all of the things were tested (apps tested on staging DB). I didn't try to make it in "dumb" way, maybe it would work... but I would not learned all this stuff I did.

Answer (score 0):

[bill-karwin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2703/bill-karwin): Migration to 8.0 requires a lot of testing and possibly rewriting some code and queries in your app. MySQL 8.0 has a lot of differences, including some deprecated/removed features, and performance regressions, etc. Start by running a separate test version of your app using MySQL 8.0, and see if it even works.

You might like a couple of free training classes from Percona related to upgrading from MySQL 5.7:

- [MySQL 5.7 End of Life Options](https://www.percona.com/blog/mysql-5-7-end-of-life-options-free-course-at-percona-university-online/)
- [How to Upgrade to MySQL 8.0](https://www.percona.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-mysql-8-0-free-course-at-percona-university-online/)